# How to Convert Data to Formatted Bytes?

Tags: java, hex, byte

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to convert data (mostly strings) into their formatted byte representation?

For example, if I enter the string "01" I'd like to get `00 01` or if I enter "0001" I'd like to get `00 00 00 01`

I've tried using ByteBuffer but the output is always 8 bits long, i.e. `01 => 00 00 00 01`

Comment: What is "formatted byte representation"? It looks like you're just tacking a 0 in front of every character and adding spaces between the resulting pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen this representation before as it sounds pretty inefficient. However what you can do is

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("01 => " + Arrays.toString(byteValues("01")));
    System.out.println("0001 => " + Arrays.toString(byteValues("0001")));
    System.out.println("0123456789ABCDEF => " + Arrays.toString(byteValues("0123456789ABCDEF")));
}

public static byte[] byteValues(String text) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[text.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++)
        bytes[i] = (byte) Character.getNumericValue(text.charAt(i));
    return bytes;
}
```

prints

```
01 => [0, 1]
0001 => [0, 0, 0, 1]
0123456789ABCDEF => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(toFormattedHexadecimal("01A"));
}

public static String toFormattedHexadecimal(String input) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        result += Integer.toHexString(ch);
        result += " ";
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code will output "30 31 41", the ASCII codes for each character.